# Web service API - Request authorization from the user - First timer

Tags: java, api, url, authentication, last.fm

[last.fm API authentication](http://www.last.fm/api/desktopauth#3)

I need to connect to a URL, let user authenticate, and then proceed. How do I do that? I have the part for opening the URL, but do not know how to wait.

```
            // 3. Request authorization from the user
            String authURL = "http://www.last.fm/api/auth/?api_key=" + key + "&token=" + token;
            java.awt.Desktop browser = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
            java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI(authURL);
            browser.browse(uri);
```

It's my first time working with web API's. I tried looking on Google and SO but didn't exactly find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry you chose this as your introduction to APIs. 5 seconds in the docs revealed that the question you have is a design flaw in their code, from the documentation:

> If the user is not logged in to Last.fm, they will be redirected to the login page before being asked to grant your application permission to use their account. On this page they will see the name of your application, along with the application description and logo as supplied in Section 1. Once the user has granted your application permission to use their account, the browser-based process is over and the user is asked to close their browser and return to your application.

That's right. They don't ping you after the user completes the authentication. They just instruct the user to close the browser. That's pretty lame for obvious reasons: how do we know if the user completed it? We don't.

You're going to structure your application so the code continues after the user comes back, perhaps giving the user a button to press that says "I'm done". Later, you'll have to handle the possibility that the user never authenticated in your other code that calls the API.

Yes, it's broken. oAuth for example will at least call you back with a token after the user completes the browser based auth step. When using oAuth in a desktop app, you can just fire up a local webserver and receive your callback there (requires your LAN to be configured properly, obviously)